# MySQL Server 8.0.13 won't start: unrecognized service

Tags: mysql

I just installed MySQL Server 8.0.13 on Ubuntu 18.04 and everything seemed to go fine until I tried to start the server. I have an identical installation that is working fine, and I followed the exact same installation procedure, but it just won't start. More detail below--any help appreciated!

```
doctor@ED-Workstation:~$ sudo service mysql start
mysql: unrecognized service
doctor@ED-Workstation:~$ sudo service mysql-server start
mysql-server: unrecognized service
doctor@ED-Workstation:~$ apt policy mysql-server
mysql-server:
  Installed: 8.0.13-1ubuntu18.04
  Candidate: 8.0.13-1ubuntu18.04
  Version table:
 *** 8.0.13-1ubuntu18.04 500
        500 http://repo.mysql.com/apt/ubuntu bionic/mysql-8.0 amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.7.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
     5.7.21-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

What am I missing?

This is a Windows 10 computer with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installed from the Microsoft Store. I have an identical installation that's working fine. I've tried a fresh install of Ubuntu and MySQL again, but something is preventing MySQL from starting.

Help! Thanks.

Comment: Some solution found it? I have the same situation, Windows 10 with Ubuntu 18.04 from Cannonical Group

Comment: Sorry, no, I ended up just installing MariaDB instead. Sometimes I wonder if WSL has some strange bugs....

Comment: I had that situation only in Windows 10 working with Ubuntu for Windows support. But with VirtualBox and using Ubuntu, no error.

Comment: Maybe mysql 8.x use systemd only, and ubuntu wsl doesn't support it. You can try genie.